# PowerShell - Check User is Member of Group X ("Get-MsolGroupMember" vs. "Get-DistributionGroupMember")

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a hard time to check if user X is a member of certain Office 365 groups. I tried the following code:

```
$members = (Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId -All).ForEach('ObjectId')

if($Office365User.ObjectId -in $members) {
   # ... user already a member of group Y
}
```

But for an unknown reason returns `Get-MsolGroupMember`not all members. I added two users 1-2 hour ago and those users are not included in the result set.

My next approach used cmdlet `Get-DistributionGroupMember` but the object in the collection do not have support property `ObjectId`.

I currently using this code to test if user X is a member of group Y:

```
function Test-UserisAlreadyGroupMember() {
    param(
        [PARAMETER(Mandatory)]
        [Microsoft.Online.Administration.Group] 
        $Group,
        [PARAMETER(Mandatory)]
        [Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]
        $Office365User
    )

    $isMember = $false;
    if($Group.GroupType -eq [GroupType]::DistributionList) {

        $members = (Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group.EmailAddress).ForEach('PrimarySmtpAddress')  

        $isMember = ($Office365User.UserPrincipalName -in $members)  

    }
    else {

        $members =  (Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId -All).ForEach('ObjectId')

        $isMember = ($Office365User.ObjectId -in $members)
    }
    $isMember
}
```

This leads to the following questions:

1. Why returns `Get-MsolGroupMember` not all members of the group?
2. Is it "save" to compare `PrimarySmtpAddress` with `UserPrincipalName` (do I have to consider situation where `UserPrincipalName` is not identical to `PrimarySmtpAddress`)
3. What is a better approach to test if user X is a member of group Y?

Comment: Did you try to use Get-UnifiedGroupLinks? MS keeps changing the Office365 cmdlets and their output from time to time. According to technet you have to use these cmdlets nowadays.

Comment: UnifiedGroup seems to work for "Office 365 Groups" but not for distribution groups

Comment: you were talking about Office365 groups, not a "regular" distribution group. Office365 groups (Unified Groups) are a special type of group. A 365 group != An exchange distribution group (a 365 group actually resides within Sharepoint Online)